# POST data from curl++ does not send

Tags: c++, curl, curlpp

I have been trying to post data from within curlpp to a web script, but it does not seem to work. On the PHP end, I simply run var_dump($_POST); to print everything received back. The $_POST global appears empty on execution.

My C++ code is as follows:

```
    std::stringstream out; 
    std::stringstream ss; 
    ss << "127.0.0.1/online.php"; 
    try 
    { 
            curlpp::Cleanup clean; 
            curlpp::Easy request; 
            curlpp::options::WriteStream ws(&out); 
            request.setOpt(ws); 
            request.setOpt<curlpp::options::Url>(ss.str()); 
            request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::Verbose(true)); 
            std::list<std::string> header; 
            header.push_back("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
            request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::HttpHeader(header)); 
            std::string test = "abcd=abcd"; 
            request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::PostFields(test)); 
            request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::PostFieldSize(test.length())); 
            request.perform(); 
    } 
    catch(curlpp::RuntimeError& e) 
    { 
            ss.str(""); 
            ss << "Error making request of type " << op << ": " << e.what(); 
            PrintError(ss.str()); 
            return ""; 
    } 
    std::cout << out.str() << std::endl;
```

Am I doing anything very obviously wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

For client-to-server uploads, the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-content-type) specifies that the content type will be one of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`. Because your web sever and/or PHP follow the standard, you should change your content type, in this case, to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Answered above, but thanks for taking the time to explain. Without any content type specifier it also wasn't working - for some reason I was assuming it would default to a working one.

Answer (score 0):

Your `content-type` is wrong, use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-content-type).